# How to store System.Type w/o late binding problem?

Tags: .net, vb.net

I'm trying to store the "DataType" field value (type System.Type) of a DbDataReader.GetSchemaTable.DataRow to a class field of type System.Type.

i.e.:

```
Class MyClass

  Private _ColumnName As String
  Private _DataType As Type

  Sub New(row As DataRow)
    _ColumnName = Convert.ToString(row("ColumnName"))
    _DataType = row("DataType")
  End Sub

End Class
```

I can resolve the late binding problem with ColumnName by casting to string but I am at a loss as how to deal with the DataType.

If I use `_DataType = row("DataType").GetType` then System.RuntimeType is stored instead of the actual type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know it's an instance of Type, then use `DirectCast(row("DataType"), Type)`

```
Class MyClass

  Private _ColumnName As String
  Private _DataType As Type

  Sub New(row As DataRow)
    _ColumnName = Convert.ToString(row("ColumnName"))
    _DataType = DirectCast(row("DataType"), Type)
  End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This seems to be faster than CType, so you get the nod.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'd want to use `Type.GetType(row("DataType"))`, assuming `row("DataType")` is the full type name as a string.

Comment: It isn't a string, it is System.Type.

Comment: @ic3b3rg - Then you'd just need to cast it like so: `(Type)(row("DataType"))`

Comment: @ic3b3rg - Sorry, VB version would be `CType(row("DataType"), Type)`

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar in a dataset,

```
oDataSet.Tables(0).Rows.GetType().ToString
```

you can try this

```
  _DataType = row(0).GetType.ToString()
```